# inferring a union type from a functions parameters

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

In Typescript when I check a variable the then branch infer variable type based on the condition:

```js
type MyType = 'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3'

const variable = 'val1' as MyType
```

```js
if (variable === 'val2' || variable === 'val3') {
    // typeof variable == 'val2' | 'val3'
}
```

The above code is chatty especially when I check for more than two values and I want to replace it with

```js
if (hasOneOf(variable, 'val2', 'val3')) {
    // typeof variable == 'val2' | 'val3'
}
```

Solution with I'm partially satisfied is:

```js
const hasOneOf = <T, U extends T>(value: T | undefined, ...values: U[]): value is U => value !== undefined && values.indexOf(value as U) >= 0
```

however it works only when I explicitly define types

```js
if (hasOneOf(variable, 'val2', 'val3')) {
    // typeof variable == MyType
}

// vs

if (hasOneOf<MyType, 'val2' | 'val3'>(variable, 'val2', 'val3')) {
    // typeof variable == 'val2' | 'val3'
}
```

Is it possible to create function hasOneOf which infer generic types and returns union defined by parameters ('val2', 'val3' => 'val2' | 'val3') ?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution which allows for a variable number of parameters, or is it fixed at 2 like in your example?

Comment: You could use [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when providing the parameters: `hasOneOf(variable, 'val2' as const, 'val3' as const)` to prevent the widening of `'val2'` and `'val3'` types to `'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3'`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://tsplay.dev/w8KVVW ?

Comment: @jsejcksn I'm looking for variable number of parameters

Comment: @captain-yossarian except it is not type safe for string unions it works! I updated it to type safe: https://tsplay.dev/wOz26W however it is bound to only one union type and I want it generic for any union type

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a solution which accepts a variable number of values for the union, below is a variation on what's in your question. You can pass a `readonly` array as the second argument and the compiler will create a union from the types of its members. (I think the addition of the array brackets and the `as const` assertion is still terser than providing type arguments):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgSTAVTPJAeAFQBpFNEBTADynLABMVECA+ACgDcBDAGxHIC4mJLr3IpBAJ3Kc6CbgE9SAbQC6ASkEi+yRmQDeAWABQiRFKggJSLWIB0MelQDywDj22ddaxMwC8iAAYAbmMAX2NjbnIoRBQoCUR-AHIRAEYkoMQAeizY+IcAcwijGGBEVlQMbFxWOIkSJRSeACYkkibuAGYklURPRAgEOLVvQxM8hJzEACIRZunEAB8ZkU7psOKomLAQAFtExFTMqZ3dgCNyCWLS8sqsHARWU4bmkk7e-sGwYdHjU1PsrlmktEJ0NkYgA)

```ts
function isInUnion <T, U extends T>(value: T, values: readonly U[]): value is U {
  return values.indexOf(value as U) >= 0;
}

let str = 'val1'; // string

if (isInUnion(str, ['val2', 'val3'] as const)) {
  str // "val2" | "val3"
}

let num = 1; // number

if (isInUnion(num, [2, 3] as const)) {
  num // 2 | 3
}
```

---

Original answer:

You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for this:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgSTAVTPJAeAZQEZEBTADylLABMVEUoAnGMAcwBpECAmMy6nQbNWbAHwAKALAAoRIgBuAQwA2IUgC5hLdh1nzGTIluJ652niZ5mAlFuVrSyesUQAfbnwDe+xE1JQIExIDuqIALyR2iRuHqFOkeEWANyyAL6ysioB2hGIAOQORPnJiAD0ZdqimTIwwIgSqBjYuBKGXIWqPPkdDgDM+TY2iD7mFchIUAAWqIgARipwEADWXIbOiABEDjyb7lv9m+myQA)

```ts
function isInUnion <S1 extends string, S2 extends string>(
  value: string,
  str1: S1,
  str2: S2,
): value is S1 | S2 {
  return value === str1 || value === str2;
}

let str = 'val1'; // string

if (isInUnion(str, 'val2', 'val3')) {
  // in this block, str is "val2" | "val3"
}
```

Comment: That only works for exactly two parameters

Comment: @GuerricP It also only works for values which extend strings, just like in the question. The question asked about two parameters.

Comment: @GuerricP Added additional solution. Does that more closely fit your interpretation of the question criteria?

Comment: @jsejcksn consider using variadic tuple types. It is not required to use `as const` assertion once you will infer the whole array

Comment: @captain-yossarian  can you elaboreate, please?

Comment: @Aik please see this https://tsplay.dev/WK7KMW

Comment: @captain-yossarian, yeah it is the solution, thanks! I only updated the argument from array to ...args so it it not need wrap test values in array